# Javascript for loop skips over function call

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, for-loop

So the issue is, when I run my program, the log looks like this: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h36Dr.jpg)

As you can see from the screenshot, update() (line 63) is being run last, after the whole program is executed. Also, if I try `console.log(threeTowers)` in the update function, it doesn't log the current state of the array, but the final state of it instead.

For example (this is a tower of hanoi solver btw):
it would console log `[] [1,2,3] []` all seven times the for loop was executed, when it should have done: `[1,2,3] [] [] ... [2,3] [1] [] ... ETC`

Here's the code:

```
for (i = 0; i < minMoves; i++) {

console.log("a: " + threeTowers[0]);
console.log("b: " + threeTowers[1]);
console.log("c: " + threeTowers[2]);
console.log(" ");
update(threeTowers[0], threeTowers[1], threeTowers[2]);

if(even){
    switch(x){
        case 1:
            AtoC();
            x=2;
            continue;
            break;
        case 2:
            AtoB();
            x=3;
            continue;
            break;
        case 3:
            BtoC();
            x=1;
            continue;
            break;
    }
}else{
    switch(x){
        case 1:
            AtoB();
            x=2;
            continue;
            break;
        case 2:
            AtoC();
            x=3;
            continue;
            break;
        case 3:
            BtoC();
            x=1;
            continue;
            break;
    }
}


}

function update(a, b, c){
    (function(index) {
    setTimeout(function() { 
        console.log(a);
        towerB.innerHTML = b;
        towerC.innerHTML = c;
    }, index*500);

})(i);
}
```

Please let me know if I need to add any of the rest of the code to make it more clear, and thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: **Never** use `continue` in a `switch` `continue` is for `while`, `do...while`, `for` and `for...in`

Answer (score 0):

When logging the array you are giving the console Just the reference to the object. The expression is evaluated once your programm terminated giving you the final result.

Try printing a stringyfied Version of rhe instance.

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(Towers));
```